# Shell Script + Python + Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, shell, import, raspberry-pi3, executable

Hello I have shell script that get executed and point python script and that get executed. Basically Shell script perform linux command that get parsed by python.

I
 am executing shell script by ./script.sh but i am getting following error.

```
./mtr-monitor.sh
./mtr-monitor.sh: line 26: ./mtr: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./save_data.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "./save_data.py", line 40, in main
    mtr_result = json.load(sys.stdin)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
./mtr-monitor.sh: line 27: ./mtr: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./save_data.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "./save_data.py", line 40, in main
    mtr_result = json.load(sys.stdin)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
./mtr-monitor.sh: line 28: ./mtr: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

totally blank wehere and how to fix. please help.thanks

Comment: How does ./mtr-monitor.sh: line 26, 27 and 28 look like?

Comment: You'll have to show some of the relevant code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: Below is the shell script .

    ( ./mtr -T -P 443 -o "LSWNBAVJMXI" --report --json --report-cycles $CYCLES $
    ( ./mtr -T -P 443 -o "LSWNBAVJMXI" --report --json --report-cycles $CYCLES $
}

while true; do
    ./mtr -T -P 443 -o "LSWNBAVJMXI" --report --json --report-cycles $CYCLES $M$
    .@AndreiCioara